# How to avoid creation of object with the same attribute

Tags: ruby

I have

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

node1 = Node.new(1)
node2 = Node.new(1)
```

What is the best way to check if a node already exists with the same name, and avoid creation of `node2`?

Comment: Store all nodes in an array and check if that array before creating new nodes?

Comment: Storing in array or set is okay but I was looking if there exist an elegant way to do this. As max answered that no in-built way to achieve this than okay but...

Comment: @HimanshuMehta I think in practice most people accomplish this with Rails model validations, but that requires a database for `validated_uniqueness_of` to work automatically .... without a database you'll end up implementing basically the same thing as in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect an exception when **::new** method is called with repeated argument, please look at [answer of @maxpleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54506050/10306509).
But if you need reference to the object that you created earlier with this argument, use other way:

```
class Name
  @names = {}
  
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def self.new(name)
    @names[name] || (@names[name] = super)
  end
end
```

Now you can test it:

```
n1 = Name.new(1)
n2 = Name.new(2)
n2a = Name.new(2)
puts n1.object_id, n2.object_id, n2a.object_id
puts n2 == n2a
```

In my case it prints:

```
5296300
5264360
5264360
true
```

Comment: As there in no in-built way to check and raise do halt initialisation and maybe proper way to do things but I find this more practical.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement this yourself. It's not that common a need, so isn't a built in way to do it.

One way is to use a Set like so so:

```
require 'set'

class Name
  NAMES = Set.new

  def initialize(name)
    if self.class::NAMES.member?(name)
      raise("already used this value") 
    else
      @name = name
      self.class::NAMES.add(name)
    end
  end
end
```

You can also use an array with `include`? but the performance is worse.

Also note that you do need to use `raise` - there isn't another way to 'cancel' initialization of an object.

Comment: Or you could use `@@names` if adding things to a constant feels wrong.

Comment: If you need not an exception but reference to the object that you created earlier with this argument, there is other way:https://stackoverflow.com/a/54522603/10306509

Comment: @IvanOlshansky oh, cool. I didn't think overwriting `new`, clever